# How to use common table expression to filter result set

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

We are trying to write a stored procedure which will allow pagination with sorting to be performed on the DB server.

We are selecting the data into a common table expression (cte) which includes the row number of that record.

In the outer SELECT, we are ordering the results based on the input parameters and then we need to apply pagination by applying a kind of "skip/take" functionality in the WHERE clause.

How can use user the "RowNumberAfterOrderBy" in the WHERE clause of the outer SELECT?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_API_GetData]
    @RequestedPage int,
    @PageSize int,
    @SortDirection nvarchar(30),
    @SortColumn nvarchar(30)
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @TotalRecords int =  (SELECT COUNT(CaseId) FROM MyTable);

    SELECT @TotalRecords as 'TotalRecords'

    ;WITH cte AS
        (SELECT [CaseId]
            ,[ActivityId]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sc.CaseId) AS RN
        FROM [dbo].[Cases] sc)
    SELECT [CaseId]
            ,[ActivityId]
            ,RN
            ,CASE @SortDirection 
                WHEN 'DESC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RN DESC)
                WHEN 'ASC' THEN  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RN)
             END AS RowNumberAfterOrderBy
    FROM cte
    --WHERE RowNumberAfterOrderBy BETWEEN (@PageSize * (@RequestedPage - 1) + 1) AND (@PageSize * @RequestedPage)
    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @SortColumn = 'CaseID' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN CaseId END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumn = 'CaseID' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN CaseId END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumn = 'ActivityId' AND @SortDirection = 'ASC' THEN ActivityId END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @SortColumn = 'ActivityId' AND @SortDirection = 'DESC' THEN ActivityId END DESC   
END

-------------------

DECLARE @PageSize int = 10;
DECLARE @RequestedPage int = 1;
DECLARE @SortDirection nvarchar(5) = 'DESC';
DECLARE @SortColumn nvarchar(30) = 'CaseID';

EXEC [sp_API_GetCases] @RequestedPage, @PageSize, @SortDirection, @SortColumn
```

Comment: You cannot use fields defined in the select clause in your where clause.  This is because the where clause is processed before the select clause (this is a consequence of the [logical processing order](https://destinationdata.wordpress.com/2016/01/10/the-logical-processing-order-3/)).  Instead you could turn your outer query into a 2nd CTE or subquery.  A new outer query would then be able to filter on `RowNumberAfterOrderBy`.

Comment: Thinking more about this I'm not sure `RowNumberAfterOrderBy` is doing what you want.  There is no guarantee that this field will match the returned order of the records.  If the 3rd case in the ORDER BY is true the data will be sorted by `ActivityId`.  But `RowNumberAfterOrderBy` will be sorted on `RN` (which is sorted on `CaseId`).  Can you supply some sample records for cases, and the output you would expect that sample to return.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think your first suggestion might be what I need. Regarding the sort for RN, I would have to add CASE statements there as well to check @SortColumn